# gcc how find -lglfw packages?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

when cpp code Linking on vscode

must define json file like below.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ 활성 파일 빌드",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "glad.c",
                "-pthread",
                "-o",
                "main",
                "main.cpp",
                "-lglfw",
                "-lGLU",
                "-lGL",
                "-lXrandr",
                "-lXxf86vm",
                "-lXinerama",
                "-lX11",
                "-lrt",
                "-ldl",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "컴파일러: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

my question is
how gcc compiler detect args parameter.

Words like -g...

Because the compiler pre-specifies words, it looks for words and pre-specifies what to do.

The -lXrandr word is the name of the package you have installed.
When this name was found,
What does the compiler do?

Does the compiler search for pre-specified folders and check for packages?

I want to know how the cpp compiler connects files on the Linux system. Do you have any links to help with this knowledge?

Comment: gcc options summary https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: I got a lot of information thanks to your simple and clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how gcc compiler detect args parameter.

Gcc is a *very* old project with a lot of options. It has [it's own command line options handling library](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/opts.c#L3119).

> The -lXrandr word is the name of the package you have installed

No, it's not the name of package. It's the name of the library.

> What does the compiler do?

Compiler [searches](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) for a library name `libXrandr.so`. In short, the file is searched in multiple directories, the [standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s06.html) library paths are searched and gcc installation path and additionally paths given with `-L` parameter and paths with `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. See also [man ld.so](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ld.so.8.en) and [man ldconfig](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ldconfig.8.pl).

> Does the compiler search for pre-specified folders

Yes.

> and check for packages?

No, a "package" is something else. Gcc is a compiler, it does not deal with "packages".

> how the cpp [*gcc] compiler connects files on the Linux system

"How" is a broad question and gcc is a very complicated program. It opens the files, [parses them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) properly, finds symbols, resolves references, generates final executable.

> Do you have any links to help with this knowledge?

[Gcc has extensive documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) and it's open source.